# Overriding the __str__ method for @classmethods in python

Tags: python, class, oop, methods, class-method

I was trying to override `__str__` and `__repr__` for class as shown in the code below. The new methods are called whenever I call the instance_method but the object calls for class_method remains the same (Please see the code snippet and the output below for clarity). Is there a way possible to override `__str__` and `__repr__` for `@classmethod` so that the value of `cls` can be changed?

I have also tried adding `__str__` and `__repr__` as `@classmethod` but nothing changed.

```py
class Abc:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Added {self.name}"

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"instance method repr"

    def instance_method(self):
        print(f"instance method {self}")

    @classmethod
    def __repr__(cls):
        return f"class method"

    @classmethod
    def __str__(cls):
        return f"class method"

    @classmethod
    def class_method(cls):
        print(f"class method '{cls}'")

    @staticmethod
    def static_method():
        print(f"static method")

    def add(self, a: int,b: int,c: int) -> int:
        return a+b+c


o = Abc("alpha")
o.class_method()
o.static_method()
o.instance_method()
Abc.static_method()
Abc.class_method()
print(o.add(1,2,3))
```

Output of the above code:

```
class method '<class '__main__.Abc'>'
static method
instance method class method
static method
class method '<class '__main__.Abc'>'
6
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Python doesn't look for a `__str__` on the class itself, just like it won't use `__str__` set on an instance. This applies to *all* special methods, see [*Special method lookup*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-lookup) in the Python datamodel:

> For custom classes, implicit invocations of special methods are only guaranteed to work correctly if defined on an object’s type, not in the object’s instance dictionary.

In short, `str(something)` does not use `something.__str__()`, it essentially uses `type(something).__str__(something)` <sup>(*)</sup> exactly because you wouldn't want the definition of `__str__` on a class to break when you use `str(class_object)`, where `class_object.__str__()` doesn't have an instance to pass in as `self`.

You'll have to define a [*metaclass*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#metaclasses), because that's the 'thing' that makes classes and is returned by `type(class_object)`:

```
class MetaAbc(type):
    def __repr__(cls):
        return "__repr__ on the metaclass"

    def __str__(cls):
        return "__str__ on the metaclass"

class Abc(metaclass=MetaAbc):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Added {self.name}"

    def __repr__(self):
        return "instance method repr"
```

The `metaclass=MetaAbc` syntax tells Python to use `MetaAbc` instead of just `type` as metaclass of the `Abc` class; now `type(Abc)` returns `MetaAbc`:

```
>>> type(Abc)
<class '__main__.MetaAbc'>
```

and `MetaAbc.__repr__` and `MetaAbc.__str__` are used when representing a class, or converting it to a string; the methods on the class are used when dealing with an instance:

```
>>> Abc
__repr__ on the metaclass
>>> print(Abc)
__str__ on the metaclass
>>> Abc('foo')
instance method repr
>>> print(Abc('foo'))
Added foo
```

The `@classmethod` decorator does not put a method into a different namespace; class methods are normal attributes of a class and are simply bound differently. `@classmethod`'s are still accessible on the instance, for example, but will *always* be passed the class object, even when accessed via the instance:

```
>>> Abc.class_method()
class method '__str__ on the metaclass'
>>> Abc("foo").class_method()
class method '__str__ on the metaclass'
```

---

<sup>(*)</sup> Python uses [*descriptor binding*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#invoking-descriptors) to implement methods, classmethods and staticmethods. Special method lookups look up the function object directly by traversing the class hierarchy to avoid triggering the normal binding process, then bind them manually. So `str(something)` translates to `next(c.__dict__['__str__'] for c in type(something).__mro__ if '__str__' in c.__dict__).__get__(something, type(something))()`. That's a bit of a mouthful, for *normal* methods this can be simplified to `type(something).__str__(something)` as that has the same effect.