# Setting magic methods on Class Objects without instances?

Tags: python

Say I have a simple object:

```
class Providers:
    Apple = "Apple"
    Banana = "Banana"
    Cherries = "Seedless Cherries"
```

I'd like to be able to do something like `if "Apple" in Providers..`, which I believe requires me to set two magic methods, `__len__` and `__getitem__`.

I tried something as simple as

```
@classmethod
def __len__(cls):
    return 3
```

but when I run `len(Providers)` I get `TypeError: object of type 'type' has no len()`

but `Providers.__len__()` returns 3.

How can I get the `len` of a class without instantiating it? Or do they need to always be instantiated with `__init__` and `self.Apple = 'Apple'?`

Comment: you've created a class object, if you want to implement those methods in the class object, then you need to implement it in the class object's class, i.e., in the metaclass. Or, more reasonably, don't try to use a class like a container.

Comment: Congratulations, you've reinvented the [`enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html).

Comment: That makes sense. I saw similar code in Airflow's definition of Executors: https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/executors/__init__.py#L57 and thought it a good practice. I'll take a look at enum.

Comment: @pedram it doesn't look like they are trying to use that class like your use-case, you seem to want a simple record/container. That looks like just name-spaced constants / enum-like class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `metclass` because When you do  `len(Providers)`  it's like you do  `type(Providers).__len__(Providers)`
and in your case:

```
       type(Providers) ==  <class 'type'>   # no __len__ method here
```

something like this:

```py
    class ProviderType(type):
        def __len__(self):
            # this will call __len__ defined on the class it self
            return self.__len__(self)


    class Providers(metaclass=ProviderType):
        Apple = "Apple"
        Banana = "Banana"
        Cherries = "Seedless Cherries"

        def __len__(self):
            return 1


    p = Providers()
    print(len(Providers))  # type(Providers).__len__(Providers)  equavalent to : ProviderType.__len__(Providers)
    print(len(p))    # type(p).__len__(p)  equal to:  Providers.__len__(p)
```

This how python Interpreter deal with dunder (magic method) method: `type(SomeObject).__dunder__(SomeOBject)`

Comment: An excellent explanation from @Martijn Pieters here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57911603/overriding-the-str-method-for-classmethods-in-python/57911666#57911666

Answer (score 1):

Use a metaclass:

```
class FooMeta(type):
    def __len__(self):
        return 10

class Foo(metaclass=FooMeta):
    pass

print(len(Foo)) # 10
```

This works because classes are in fact objects, i.e., they are instances of they metaclasses

Comment: yeah, but this is totally an over-engineered solution to a problem that shouldn't exist in the first place

Comment: I agreed, they right way would be extend the container classes where made to be extended https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-container-types

Comment: generally, I prefer composition over inheritance, especially in this case which wouldn't be a natural extension of any of the container classes. The OP seems to almost want an enum, but that is just speculating on my part.

Comment: I prefer FP over OOP. Composing lead to less coupled code, but I think that metaclasses are so mind-blowing that they need to be show, this is a good example of a bad use of metaclasses, but still is a good example

Comment: I'm really just trying to validate that incoming data matches one of the defined constants for a Provider. I suppose I could do something like `if var in Providers.__dict__.values()` but that seemed ugly.

Comment: `if var in dir(Providers)` would work, I guess------- edit ---- no it will not, you want values not keys :)

Comment: Use the enum class, or a namedtuple