# How can I document methods inherited from a metaclass?

Tags: python, python-3.x, metaclass, class-method, docstring

Consider the following metaclass/class definitions:

```
class Meta(type):
    """A python metaclass."""
    def greet_user(cls):
        """Print a friendly greeting identifying the class's name."""
        print(f"Hello, I'm the class '{cls.__name__}'!")

    
class UsesMeta(metaclass=Meta):
    """A class that uses `Meta` as its metaclass."""
```

[As we know](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59341761/what-are-the-differences-between-a-classmethod-and-a-metaclass-method), defining a method in a metaclass means that it is inherited by the class, and can be used by the class. This means that the following code in the interactive console works fine:

```
>>> UsesMeta.greet_user()
Hello, I'm the class 'UsesMeta'!
```

However, one major downside of this approach is that any documentation that we might have included in the definition of the method is lost. If we type `help(UsesMeta)` into the interactive console, we see that there is no reference to the method `greet_user`, let alone the docstring that we put in the method definition:

```
Help on class UsesMeta in module __main__:
class UsesMeta(builtins.object)
 |  A class that uses `Meta` as its metaclass.
 |  
 |  Data descriptors defined here:
 |  
 |  __dict__
 |      dictionary for instance variables (if defined)
 |  
 |  __weakref__
 |      list of weak references to the object (if defined)
```

Now of course, the `__doc__` attribute for a class [is writable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056983/how-do-i-programmatically-set-the-docstring), so one solution would be to rewrite the metaclass/class definitions like so:

```
from pydoc import render_doc
from functools import cache

def get_documentation(func_or_cls):
    """Get the output printed by the `help` function as a string"""
    return '\n'.join(render_doc(func_or_cls).splitlines()[2:])


class Meta(type):
    """A python metaclass."""

    @classmethod
    @cache
    def _docs(metacls) -> str:
        """Get the documentation for all public methods and properties defined in the metaclass."""

        divider = '\n\n----------------------------------------------\n\n'
        metacls_name = metacls.__name__
        metacls_dict = metacls.__dict__

        methods_header = (
            f'Classmethods inherited from metaclass `{metacls_name}`'
            f'\n\n'
        )

        method_docstrings = '\n\n'.join(
            get_documentation(method)
            for method_name, method in metacls_dict.items()
            if not (method_name.startswith('_') or isinstance(method, property))
        )

        properties_header = (
            f'Classmethod properties inherited from metaclass `{metacls_name}`'
            f'\n\n'
        )

        properties_docstrings = '\n\n'.join(
            f'{property_name}\n{get_documentation(prop)}'
            for property_name, prop in metacls_dict.items()
            if isinstance(prop, property) and not property_name.startswith('_')
        )

        return ''.join((
            divider,
            methods_header,
            method_docstrings,
            divider,
            properties_header,
            properties_docstrings,
            divider
        ))


    def __new__(metacls, cls_name, cls_bases, cls_dict):
        """Make a new class, but tweak `.__doc__` so it includes information about the metaclass's methods."""

        new = super().__new__(metacls, cls_name, cls_bases, cls_dict)
        metacls_docs = metacls._docs()

        if new.__doc__ is None:
            new.__doc__ = metacls_docs
        else:
            new.__doc__ += metacls_docs

        return new

    def greet_user(cls):
        """Print a friendly greeting identifying the class's name."""
        print(f"Hello, I'm the class '{cls.__name__}'!")

    
class UsesMeta(metaclass=Meta):
    """A class that uses `Meta` as its metaclass."""
```

This "solves" the problem; if we now type `help(UsesMeta)` into the interactive console, the methods inherited from `Meta` are now fully documented:

```
Help on class UsesMeta in module __main__:
class UsesMeta(builtins.object)
 |  A class that uses `Meta` as its metaclass.
 |  
 |  ----------------------------------------------
 |  
 |  Classmethods inherited from metaclass `Meta`
 |  
 |  greet_user(cls)
 |      Print a friendly greeting identifying the class's name.
 |  
 |  ----------------------------------------------
 |  
 |  Classmethod properties inherited from metaclass `Meta`
 |  
 |  
 |  
 |  ----------------------------------------------
 |  
 |  Data descriptors defined here:
 |  
 |  __dict__
 |      dictionary for instance variables (if defined)
 |  
 |  __weakref__
 |      list of weak references to the object (if defined)
```

That's an awful lot of code to achieve this goal, however. *Is there a better way?*

**How does the standard library do it?**

I'm also curious about the way certain classes in the standard library manage this. If we have an `Enum` definition like so:

```
from enum import Enum

class FooEnum(Enum):
    BAR = 1
```

Then, typing `help(FooEnum)` into the interactive console includes this snippet:

```
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Readonly properties inherited from enum.EnumMeta:
 |  
 |  __members__
 |      Returns a mapping of member name->value.
 |      
 |      This mapping lists all enum members, including aliases. Note that this
 |      is a read-only view of the internal mapping.
```

How exactly does the `enum` module achieve this?

**The reason why I'm using metaclasses here, rather than just defining `classmethod`s in the body of a class definition**

Some methods that you might write in a metaclass, such as `__iter__`, `__getitem__` or `__len__`, [*can't* be written](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57911666/13990016) as `classmethod`s, but can lead to extremely expressive code if you define them in a metaclass. The `enum` module is an [excellent example](https://docs.python.org/3.11/howto/enum.html) of this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `help()` function relies on `dir()`, which currently does not always give consistent results. This is why your method gets lost in the generated interactive documentation. There's a open python issue on this topic which explains the problem in more detail: see [bugs 40098](https://bugs.python.org/issue40098) (esp. the first bullet-point).

In the meantime, a work-around is to define a custom `__dir__` in the meta-class:

```
class Meta(type):
    """A python metaclass."""
    def greet_user(cls):
        """Print a friendly greeting identifying the class's name."""
        print(f"Hello, I'm the class '{cls.__name__}'!")

    def __dir__(cls):
        return super().__dir__() + [k for k in type(cls).__dict__ if not k.startswith('_')]

class UsesMeta(metaclass=Meta):
    """A class that uses `Meta` as its metaclass."""
```

which produces:

```
Help on class UsesMeta in module __main__:

class UsesMeta(builtins.object)
 |  A class that uses `Meta` as its metaclass.
 |
 |  Methods inherited from Meta:
 |
 |  greet_user() from __main__.Meta
 |      Print a friendly greeting identifying the class's name.
```

This is essentially what [enum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#module-enum) does - although its implementation is obviously a little more sophisticated than mine! (The module is written in python, so for more details, just search for "__dir__" in the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/enum.py)).

Comment: A nearly perfect answer -- the only issue being that by overriding `__dir__` in this way, the output from `help` loses any information about methods defined in `UsesMeta` -- it now *only* has information about methods implemented in the metaclass! The solution is to have this as the `__dir__` definition instead: `return super().__dir__() + [k for k in type(cls).__dict__ if not k.startswith('_')]`

Comment: Okay - I said it wasn't sophisticated! I will update my example with your suggestion.

Comment: It wasn't a criticism -- was just giving feedback on how I had adapted it for my use case! Thanks very much for the helpful and informative answer.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't looked at the rest of the stdlib, but `EnumMeta` accomplishes this by overriding the `__dir__` method (i.e. specifying it in the `EnumMeta` class):

```
class EnumMeta(type):
    .
    .
    .
    def __dir__(self):
        return (
                ['__class__', '__doc__', '__members__', '__module__']
                + self._member_names_
                )
```

Comment: Works perfectly -- thanks so much! I had no idea that `help` depended on the implementation of `__dir__`.